# How to ignore/mask nan values when doing cosine similarity

Tags: python, numpy, missing-data, cosine-similarity

I have an array with nan values, for example:

`a = np.array([[np.nan, 1, 5], [5,np.nan,np.nan]])`

I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity (trying with `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`) but it of course does not work with nan values.

I have tried masking the array with `b = np.ma.MaskedArray(a, mask = np.isnan(a))`, but that gives the same error. Is there a way to calculate the cosine similarity while ignoring the null values, or is imputation necessary?

Comment: Cosine similarity does not make sense for vectors with missing values. You're essentially looking to define your own measure of similarity, and perhaps you should start from an expected output in the given example.

Comment: Are there any similarity measures that do make sense in this case? I know there is one for Euclidean, but not sure if that's as performant.